# Postgres - multilevel parent child relation data

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, parent-child, hierarchical-data

We have a parent child relation as below.

[image]

Script to generate tables as below.

```
create table dependency ( packageid int, dependant_packageid int);
insert into dependency values (2,1);
insert into dependency values (3,1);
insert into dependency values (4,1);
insert into dependency values (5,2);
insert into dependency values (6,3);
insert into dependency values (7,4);
insert into dependency values (7,5);
insert into dependency values (8,5);
insert into dependency values (8,3);
insert into dependency values (4,5);
insert into dependency values (6,4);
insert into dependency values (5,3);
```

We wanted to get data based on below mentioned quer.

1. for the given package get the possible dependant hierarchy

```
Ex:
packageid : 6
Result should be: [(3,1),(4,1),(4,5,2,1),(4,5,3,1)]
packageid : 7
Result should be: [(4,1),(4,5,2,1),(4,5,3,1)]
packageid : 8
Result should be: [(5,2,1),(5,3,1),(3,1)]
```

2. for the given package get the list of parent packages

```
Ex:
1 - 2,3,4
2 - 5
3 - 6,8,5
4 - 7,6
5 - 7,8,4
```

3. If we need to maintain this kind of parent child relation (many to many), what should be ideal schema structure (Keeping in mind performance) ?

Appreciate any help....happy coding....:)

Comment: Your schema is fine for this. What you need here is called a RECURSIVE CTE. It's a two part query inside a CTE that iteratively joins back to itself until the join fails.

Comment: Fyi, here's an [older SO post about alternatives for an adjacency list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/4003419) you might be an interesting read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick shot at a recursive query that spits out your distinct full dependency lists for each id:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
    --Recursive Seed
    SELECT packageid as initialid, 
        packageid,
        dependant_packageid, 
        CAST(packageid || ',' || dependant_packageid as varchar(30)) as path,
        1 as depth
    FROM dependency
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive Term
    SELECT initialid,
        dependency.packageid,
        dependency.dependant_packageid,
        CAST(rcte.path || ',' || dependency.dependant_packageid as varchar(30)),
        rcte.depth + 1
    FROM rcte
        INNER JOIN dependency ON rcte.dependant_packageid = dependency.packageid
)
SELECT r1.initialid as packageid, path as dependant_packages 
FROM rcte r1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rcte r2
        ON r2.path LIKE r1.path || '%' AND r1.depth < r2.depth
WHERE r2.initialid IS NULL
ORDER BY r1.path;
```

That recursive CTE has two parts. The `recursive seed` is run once. It gathers the records from the table(s) that will be initially fed into the second part, the `recursive term` which will iterate until its JOIN fails. In that recursive term we join the CTE `rcte` back to the table and join the `dependant_packageid` of the CTE to the `packageid` of the table.

Finally the `SELECT` statement refernces those results from the CTE and self-joins to find the longest distinct path from all those iterations.

Using this same recursive logic you can get your remaining record sets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an primary key to your table:

```
create table dependency (serial id, packageid int, dependant_packageid int);
```

Then, to get the hierarchy you could use a query like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
    SELECT id,
        packageid AS initial_packageid,
        dependant_packageid, 
        ARRAY[dependant_packageid::text]::text[] as path,
        1 as depth
    FROM dependency
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rcte.id,
        rcte.initial_packageid,
        dependency.dependant_packageid,
        rcte.path || dependency.dependant_packageid::text,
        rcte.depth + 1
    FROM rcte
        JOIN dependency ON rcte.dependant_packageid = dependency.packageid ),
    cte_hierarchy AS (
        SELECT initial_packageid AS packageid,
            (ARRAY_AGG( '(' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(path, ',') || ')' ORDER BY depth DESC))[1] AS hierarchy
        FROM rcte
        GROUP BY id, initial_packageid )
SELECT packageid, STRING_AGG(hierarchy, ',')
FROM cte_hierarchy
GROUP BY packageid
ORDER BY packageid
```

And to get the parent packages simply use:

```
SELECT dependant_packageid AS packageid, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT packageid)
FROM dependency
GROUP BY dependant_packageid
ORDER BY dependant_packageid
```